# AJAX URL not working unless in root directory

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've searched around for this answer but I can't find an answer to this specific problem. (Firstly I'm quite new to ajax) I have a dynamic dropdown menu which populates it's items through an sql query. I have been trying to organise all of the included files, keeping everything in order - but this creates an issue with all of my ajax requests.

When I put these ajax.php files into a directory and change the URL on the javascript - it breaks the code and can't connect to the database. These files ARE being found as the console window throws "Error 500" errors when the path is typed incorrectly. I know there's probably a simple fix but I can't seem to find anywhere on here or on the internet which has this particular issue.

Here's a copy of my jquery snip

```js
$(".dropdown01").change(function() {
    var type_id = $(this).val();
    var post_id = 'id=' + type_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/ajaxMenu.php", //File needs to be in root. '/ajaxMenu.php' 
        data: post_id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(menuItems) {
            $(".dropdown02").html(menuItems);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a snip of the ajax file

```js
include('databaseConnect.php');
if($_POST['id']){
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table01` WHERE item_id='$id'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['item_id'].'">'.$row['item_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could shed some light on this issue that would be great!

Comment: At first glance, I'd say that the error is caused by your `include('databaseConnect.php')`. If you move the `ajaxMenu.php` file to another folder, you probably also need to update the path to the file it needs to include. But I'm guessing. When you get a 500 error, your server's log files should contain the actual error. What do your logs say?

Comment: Your ajax.php file is including a file named `databaseConnect.php` which it assumes is in the same directory.  If you are moving your ajax.php file to a different directory, you will need to update the include path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhmmm.. this might sound dumb but...

Are you moving your databaseConnect.php?

If not you need to change the include path from:

```
include('databaseConnect.php');
```

to

```
include('../databaseConnect.php');
```

Comment: thanks! Yes that seemed to work perfectly. It turns out I've been searching for the wrong problem this whole week. I thought it was an issue with the way j-query was handling the path as it only seemed to be affected by the directory the file was in, turns out all my time was wasted editing the wrong part of the code.